# Passing form variables through URL

Tags: html, forms, url, http-post, http-get

What I want to accomplish is logging in to a website by simply typing in the form variables in the URL.

HTML  code:

```
    <form action="httpclient.html" onsubmit="return checkSubmit();" method="post"           target="_parent" name="frmHTTPClientLogin">
    <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="191">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input border="1" style="width:150px" maxlength="60" name="username">
    <label>Password</label></pre>
    <input type="password" border="1" style="width:150px" autocomplete="off" name="password" maxlength="60">
```

This is the relevant past of the code. Now I want to login to this site http://10.100.56.55/httpclient.html just by passing values typed in the url. Firstly is it possible. If yes then what exactly do i need to type for userame :name and password being pass ?
and what encoded URL will be passed in POST method if any?

Comment: The form has `POST` as it's `method`, which means you won't be able to replicate it's functionality by adding a query string to the URL (a GET request). You would need to send a POST request to the URL instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to type the Querystring in for the username and password, you need to do this in the address field of your browser:

```
http://10.100.56.55/?username=name&password=pass
```

EDIT:
You need to find out where the form is going and what it's doing. For this, you need to check what the submit javascript function called 'checkSubmit()' is doing. You can do this by opening the page in your browser and doing a view source. If the javascript is external to the html file, check the js links on the page and open those up to find that function. The function might have the querystring parameters you're looking for.

Comment: do you know the username and password to this site?
is this an attempt at hacking? lol
your question asked about typing the fields into the URL, so my answer tells you how :P

Comment: no this is not a hacking attempt. I am trying to create a GUI for logging into the site. so I require to know the exact string that must be passed to the server

Answer (score 5):

Change `method="post"` to `method="get"`

Comment: This is not my website. so how can i change the form method ?

Comment: oh, I might have misunderstood the first time I read it. Not sure if I understand what you are trying to do :P

Comment: Ok ... I'm trying to use urllib to login to cyberoam. But I don't know the exact query string to pass

Answer (score 2):

the issue was in the input tag `<input type="hidden" name="min_price" value="200">` forward slash was missing,I have added the forward slash and it works now `<input type="hidden" name="min_price" value="200"/>`.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Products" name="search" value="search" id="search">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Products" name="search" value="search" id="search2">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='\search.php?search='+ document.getElementById('search').value+'&search2='+document.getElementById('search2').value;"> Search</button>
```

Comment: The post string looks like  http://localhost:88/OrderSystem/search.php?search=username&search2=password

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do that; the form would have to use the GET method.